# Assembly int 13h ah=42h crashes

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, masm

I have an x86 assembly code which calls a `proc` to read master boot record.

```
STACKSEG SEGMENT PARA STACK 'stack'
DW 512 DUP(?)
STACKSEG ENDS

DATASEG1 SEGMENT PARA 'data'

    mbr db 512 dup(?)

    DAP db      10h    ;size of DAP
    z db      0     ;zero
    dsize dw 1h     ;number of sectors to read
    
    ;point to memory
    dap_offset dw      ?     ;offset
    dap_segment dw      ?  ;segment
    dap_addr dw      0     ;disk address
    dap_addr2 dw 0
    dap_addr3 dw 0
    dap_addr4 dw 0

DATASEG1 ENDS


CODESEG1 SEGMENT PARA 'code'
    _main PROC FAR
    ASSUME CS:CODESEG1,DS:DATASEG1,SS:STACKSEG

    call _get_mbr
    ASSUME CS:CODESEG1
     ;;some other code
    int 20h
_main endp
CODESEG1 ENDS


CODESEG2 SEGMENT PARA 'code'
    ASSUME CS:CODESEG2
    _get_mbr proc far
        ;;read MBR
    g:
    mov ax, ds
    mov dap_segment, ax
    mov ax, offset mbr
    mov dap_offset, ax
    
    mov si, offset DAP
    mov dl, 81h
    mov ah, 42h
    int 13h
            
    ret
   _get_mbr endp


    CODESEG2 ENDS 
   end _main
```

However, when the code runs `int 13h`, it changes the `CS` an `IP` to a number (04BA) which I was not defined in the code and causes the program to crash.

Running the code in DOS debug, when it runs int 13h with `p`, it crashes the whole OS and needs to restart.

Comment: Might be you need to initialise `ds`?

Comment: I have initialized it in the `_main` however re-initializing the `ds` in the `CODESEG2` made no difference.

Comment: I'm with ECM that you are missing startup code to set DS if this is going to be a DOS EXE program `mov AX, DATASEG1` `mov DS, AX` . You would normally do that in `_main` before everything else. I'd also ask you if you are reading from the right drive. Is there a drive 81h on your system (second hard drive device)

Comment: you're correct. the problem was that I just assumed DS:DATASEG1 but forgot to initialize it in the _main

Comment: Another issue is that if this is a DOS EXE you probably should be using `int 21h` `ah=4ch` to exit and not `int 20h`

Comment: I have seen buggy BIOSes that assumed that the segment in the DAP and the `ES` register contain the same value. You should also consider this.